# What do you call a person placing bets?

Tags: word-usage, nouns

I'm trying to figure out the proper word for a person who is placing bets on various matches at a betting company. I've found only these: *bettor* / *better* , *punter*, but I have literally no idea about usage of these.

Please give me some insight into this problem.

Comment: Have you looked up a good dictionary for definitions and uses of those words?

Comment: I was trying to get this explained by someone who understand how these words are used in context. There are no resources on how to use these words and my common dictionary didn't help me at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Better, bettor, punter, gambler- someone who bets.

Reference: *Oxforddictionaries.com*

*Punter*- [informal](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/punter) , chiefly BrE, a person who gambles, places a bet, or makes a risky investment.

*Bettor-* [chiefly AmE](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bettor), a person who bets, especially on a regular basis.

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question, it just repeats the definition of the three words the asker is asking about.

Comment: 'punter' is not used in the US. 'bettor' would be understood but would sound weird in AmE.

Comment: This answer also reproduces dictionary definitions without the correct attribution. Sources **must** be identified in plain text and not *just* by a link.

Answer (score 4):

We call them "gamblers", if they are placing bets for themselves, "bookies" if they are placing bets for others. (US)

Interestingly, the verb *to gamble* is not used as often in this sense - but usually more figuratively. One *lays* (or places) bets, and *plays* the horses - in the same way that one would "play" poker or blackjack.

Comment: Clearly the word *gambler* is used in Britain too. But it is less specific to *punter*. *Punting* is the act of actually placing the bet. A *punter* is a gambler. The fact that there are two words, invoking the general and the particular, is an example of the very wide range of vocabulary in everyday use in Britain.

Answer (score 0):

In the UK those betting on horse racing etc are almost universally known as ***punters***.

The OED attests this use since its first example from 1860 .

***Punter*** is also used for one who bets against the bank at a number of card games. This is perhaps from the French *ponte*, but the etymology of both uses is uncertain, and it is not even known if they are from a common root.

Comment: A cautionary note: a _punter_ is also a colloquial term for the customer of a prostitute.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I was looking for something like the answer down.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Also a swindler or member of a criminal gang. A *punter* can be any of about six different things, all situated on the fringes of 'respectable' society. And that's  before you even get into the matters of punting boats, or punting footballs.